# Akka Spring integration does not set actor's name

Tags: java, spring, akka

I am creating my Akka actors using [Akka Spring integration](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-akka-java-spring)
. The problem is that it seems to create unnamed aactors which is not recommended. My Akka config is

```
AkkaDemo{
akka.actor.deployment  {

   /rootActor {
        nr-of-instances = 5   
    }
```

}

When I create my actor as

```
ActorRef rootActor = system.actorOf(SpringExtProvider.get(system).create("rootActor").withRouter(new RoundRobinPool(5)), "root");
```

The actor's path is

```
akka://AkkaDemo/user/root/$a
```

Which means that the "rootActor" name is ignored and Akka created an actor with the name $a. I am wondering if there is a way to create a named actor via Spring integration?

Comment: It seems that the issue is with the router which hijacks the actor name. If I skip the router and just call 
    ActorRef rootActor = system.actorOf(SpringExtProvider.get(system).create("rootActor"), "root");
The path will be
    akka://AkkaDemo/user/root.
I am not sure if it is at all possible to specify the router and actor names together

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the the router: if an actor is created using .withRouter(...) the router actor receives the actor's name and the instances of the actors are given $.. names by Akka